# Estructurar Json en html

Tags: javascript, html, json, api

a todos, Gracias por ver mi pregunta, espero puedan ayudarme.  es lo siguiente..

Tengo el siguiente codigo.

en html

```
<div id="summary"></div>
```

En Js tengo

```
   function callurl() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', 
        type: "GET", 
        dataType: "json", 
        success: function (msg) {
            JsonpCallback(msg);
        }, 
        error: function () {
            ErrorFunction();
        }
    });
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {
    document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML = json.title;
}
callurl();
```

Necesito estructurar el json, de la siguiente forma en el html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con id en cada variable. un ejemplo seria

```
<h4>Post ID:<span id="postid"></span></h4>
<h1>Titulo:<span id="titulo"></span></h1>
<h5>Contenido: <span id="contenido"></span></h5>
```

Alguien puede ayudarme.

Tengo algunas pruebas en 
https://jsfiddle.net/kw8ztdw6/4/

---

ACTUALIZACION 
Gracias a @jorius

Hice la actualizacion perfectamente
en https://jsfiddle.net/kw8ztdw6/12/

Ahora lo que me pregunto, como puedo que

si tengo json de la siguiente forma..

```
{
   "orders":[
      {
         "id":12535,
         "order_number":12535,
         "created_at":"2017-03-26T18:10:00Z",
         "updated_at":"2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
         "completed_at":"2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
         "status":"processing",
         "currency":"BHD",
         "total":"30.00",
         "subtotal":"30.00",
         "total_line_items_quantity":1,
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "total_shipping":"0.00",
         "cart_tax":"0.00",
         "shipping_tax":"0.00",
         "total_discount":"0.00",
         "shipping_methods":"",
         "payment_details":{
            "method_id":"credimax",
            "method_title":"Visa \/ Master Card",
            "paid":true
         }
      },      
      {
         "id":33333,
         "order_number":33333,
         "created_at":"2017-03-26T18:10:00Z",
         "updated_at":"2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
         "completed_at":"2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
         "status":"processing",
         "currency":"BHD",
         "total":"10.00",
         "subtotal":"10.00",
         "total_line_items_quantity":1,
         "total_tax":"0.00",
         "total_shipping":"0.00",
         "cart_tax":"0.00",
         "shipping_tax":"0.00",
         "total_discount":"0.00",
         "shipping_methods":"",
         "payment_details":{
            "method_id":"credimax",
            "method_title":"Visa \/ Master Card",
            "paid":true
         }
      },
   ]
}
```

como puedo, mostrar

```
<h5>Order numero: <span id="order_number"></span></h5>
<h5>Fecha: <span id="created_at"></span></h5>
```

de todos...

Comment: Puedes usar Handlebarsjs http://handlebarsjs.com/ para pitar el json como tu quieres, es muy fácil implementarlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el `json` que recibes es un *arreglo*, por lo tanto debes recorrerlo con un *ciclo*, además, como veo que estás usando `jquery` puedes hacer uso de los selectores y métodos de este para hacer más simple tu código, con `append` agregamos la información a tu `div`

```js
function callurl() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      JsonpCallback(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      ErrorFunction();
    }
  });
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    $('#summary').append('<b>Post:</b> ' + json[i].id + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<b>Título:</b> ' + json[i].title + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<b>Descripción:</b> ' + json[i].body + '<br />');
    $('#summary').append('<hr />');
  }
}

callurl();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Respecto a la actualización de tu pregunta, sería básicamente lo mismo, solo que accederías a un nivel más dentro del objeto, es decir:

```js
var OrdersObject = {
  "orders": [{
      "id": 12535,
      "order_number": 12535,
      "created_at": "2017-03-26T18:10:00Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
      "completed_at": "2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
      "status": "processing",
      "currency": "BHD",
      "total": "30.00",
      "subtotal": "30.00",
      "total_line_items_quantity": 1,
      "total_tax": "0.00",
      "total_shipping": "0.00",
      "cart_tax": "0.00",
      "shipping_tax": "0.00",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "shipping_methods": "",
      "payment_details": {
        "method_id": "credimax",
        "method_title": "Visa \/ Master Card",
        "paid": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 33333,
      "order_number": 33333,
      "created_at": "2017-03-26T18:10:00Z",
      "updated_at": "2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
      "completed_at": "2017-03-27T07:25:49Z",
      "status": "processing",
      "currency": "BHD",
      "total": "10.00",
      "subtotal": "10.00",
      "total_line_items_quantity": 1,
      "total_tax": "0.00",
      "total_shipping": "0.00",
      "cart_tax": "0.00",
      "shipping_tax": "0.00",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "shipping_methods": "",
      "payment_details": {
        "method_id": "credimax",
        "method_title": "Visa \/ Master Card",
        "paid": true
      }
    }
  ]
};

for (var i = 0; i < OrdersObject.orders.length; i++) {
  $('#summary').append('<b>Número de orden: </b>' + OrdersObject.orders[i].order_number + '<br />');
  $('#summary').append('<b>Fecha: </b>' +
    OrdersObject.orders[i].created_at);
  $('#summary').append('<hr />');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Comment: Jorius, un código mas elegante que el mío +1

Comment: @jorius Buen Codigo! mil gracias, actualice mi pregunta, me puedes ayudar?

Comment: @mauricio-arias-olave Tu codigo tambien es bueno! mil gracias por aportar! amigo, ya entiendo varias cosas, de las dos forma

Comment: @JuanDavid He actualizado mi respuesta respecto a lo último que pusiste en tu pregunta

Comment: @JuanDavid, puedes guiarte con las respuestas que la comunidad te ha dado. Yo te recomendaría crear una nueva pregunta, pero primero, prueba con los conocimientos que has adquirido con estas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: @Jorius Gracias!!! me ayudo mucho.

Answer (score 2):

Vas bien. Lo que te falta es obtener los valores de los atributos del objeto.

*(Además de que cada elemento debe tener un ID único)* he modificado tu código para generar los resultados así:

```js
function callurl() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      JsonpCallback(msg);
    },
    error: function() {
      ErrorFunction();
    }
  });
}

function JsonpCallback(json) {

  // Variables internas.
  var postId = 0;
  var title = "";
  var body = "";
  var HTML_FINAL = "";

  // Aquí se recorre el objeto JSON devuelto por la llamada.
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

    // Asigno los valores a las variables locales.
    postId = json[i].id;
    title = json[i].title;
    body = json[i].body;

    // Armo el HTML que se colocará en el div "summary":
    HTML_FINAL += '<h4>Post ID:<span id="postid_' + postId + '">' + postId + '</span></h4>' +
      '<h1>Titulo:<span id="titulo_' + i + '">' + title + '</span></h1>' +
      '<h5>Contenido: <span id="contenido' + i + '">' + body + '</span></h5>';
  }

  // Después de salir del ciclo, la variable "HTML_FINAL" tendrá
  // toda la información obtenida. En este paso, se asigna
  // los resultados.
  document.getElementById('summary').innerHTML = HTML_FINAL;
}
callurl();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="summary"></div>
```

Puedes acceder a tu jsfiddle modificado [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/kw8ztdw6/9/).